# Group a multidimensional array by a key in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have this code :

```
 [
    {
        "info": {
            "a": 65535,
            "b": 50,
        },
        "test": {
            "m": "10300",
            "id": "2008",
        },
    },
    {
        "info": {
            "a": 65535,
            "b": 50,
        },
        "test": {
            "m": "10300",
            "id": "2008",
        },
    },
    {
        "info": {
            "a": 65535,
            "b": 50,
        },
        "test": {
            "m": "10300",
            "id": "2009",
        },
    },
]
```

I want to have :

```
[
    "2008" : [
        {
            "info": {
                "a": 65535,
                "b": 50,
             },
            "test": {
                "m": "10300",
                "id": "2008",
             },
        },
        {
            "info": {
                "a": 65535,
                "b": 50,
            },
            "test": {
                "m": "10300",
                "id": "2008",
            },
       },
    ]
    "2009" : [
        {
            "info": {
                "a": 65535,
                "b": 50,
            },
            "test": {
                "m": "10300",
                "id": "2009",
            },
        },
     ]
```

The idea is to group by key value based on column id. I'm new in python an have no idea how to do that. Please help me. Thx in advance. If you could provide some ideas will be great.I found some examples but can't solve this problem anyway.

My solution :

```
value = [i for i in array]
res = sorted(value, key=lambda x: x["id"], reverse=True)
```

Comment: Please show what you've tried...

Comment: @I'L'I I edited the question

Comment: Your desired output is a syntax error.

Answer (score 3):

I think you want a `dictionary` where each key is the `id` and the value is your object.

Try the following. `data` is your array of data.

```
new = {}
for item in data:
    item_id = item['test']['id']
    new[item_id] = item
```

You could also use a dictionary comprehension.

```
new = {item['test']['id']: item for item in data}
```

Comment: Is getting only the first value

Comment: can you take a look please ?

Comment: @George what do you mean?

Comment: I get : for each id only one item, for example : `
    "2008" : [
        {
            "info": {
                "a": 65535,
                "b": 50,
             },
            "test": {
                "m": "10300",
                "id": "2008",
             },
        },]`

Comment: But I have 2 items for key 2008

Comment: you understand the idea ?

Answer (score 1):

Use `itertools.groupby`

```
from itertools import groupby
f = lambda d: d['test']['id']
res = {k:list(v) for k,v in groupby(sorted(l, key=f), f)}
pprint(res)
```

**Output**

```
{'2008': [{'info': {'a': 65535, 'b': 50},
           'test': {'id': '2008', 'm': '10300'}},
          {'info': {'a': 65535, 'b': 50},
           'test': {'id': '2008', 'm': '10300'}}],
 '2009': [{'info': {'a': 65535, 'b': 50},
           'test': {'id': '2009', 'm': '10300'}}]}
```

Answer (score 1):

Let us suppose

```
array = [
   {
    "info": {
        "a": 65535,
        "b": 50,
        },
    "test": {
        "m": "10300",
        "id": "2008",
        },
    },
    {
    "info": {
        "a": 65535,
        "b": 50,
        },
    "test": {
        "m": "10300",
        "id": "2008",
        },
    },
    {
    "info": {
        "a": 65535,
        "b": 50,
        },
    "test": {
        "m": "10300",
        "id": "2009",
        },
    },
]
```

Then you can get the expected result by using

```
modified_data = {}
for entry in array:
    index = entry['test']['id']
    try:
        modified_data[index].append(entry)
    except KeyError:
        modified_data[index] = [entry]
print modified_data
```

Now let's analyze your code

```
value = [i for i in array]
```

After this value will be equal to array itself, assuming that your array initialization is same as mine.

```
res = sorted(value, key=lambda x: x["id"], reverse=True)
```

If the above statement is correct then value will not have 'id' hence it will throw an error.

Also, a list can't have a key-value pair. You have to use a dictionary for that.